# Can't I just simply get the day name I18n-ed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm pretty new with rails also with ruby.

I just want to get the `I18n.l` of a day name or a month name, without a whole date or time. Because I don't have it.

For example, I simply want to internationalize for example

```
= l Date::DAYNAMES[0]
```

or

```
= l Date::MONTHNAME[0]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access the day names with:

```
I18n.t(:"date.day_names")
#=> ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

and the month names with:

```
I18n.t(:"date.month_names")
#=> [nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

Comment: Or, in other words, Date::DAYNAMES[0] would be translated to I18n.t(:"date.day_names")[0]

Answer (score 3):

I'm from brazil. In my rails applications I have a pt-BR.yml inside config/locales.
It's like this:

```
"pt-BR":
  date:    
    day_names:
      - Domingo
      - Segunda
      - Terça
      - Quarta
      - Quinta
      - Sexta
      - Sábado
```

It's the same for month names, etc... In my application.rb I have

```
config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
```

That gives me translated names. Read the [I18N guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, that information is not exposed directly by the Rails I18N API.  Probably easiest to make up a date in the month or weekday you need, localize it, and extract the desired string.

Comment: I'm afraid so... I find something like this, I18n.t "date.abbr_day_names" but I guess I need to turn into array first

Comment: `Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.map{|s| I18n.t s}` may work if you have defined translations for them...

Comment: @Mark Reed, I do have defined translations, in fact I stumbled upon this I18n.t(Date::DAYNAMES[@prod.start_day]) because it gave me " translation missing" for the item and I just had to append the yaml file.  However Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).map{|s| I18n.t s}  returns only EN values